# How to access GET data while posting data?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am writing an api for an image labelling game using Django Rest Framework's APIView class.

The game implies that a user will see a picture (resource) and label it with one or more labels (tagging). Since the picture is sent an an object through the GET request and a label references the picture the label was posted for, I somehow need to access the id of the picture when storing a label in the database.

Currently, I am testing my POST request, which is pretty standard:

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        tag_serializer = TagSerializer(data=request.data)
        tagging_serializer = TaggingSerializer(data=request.data)

        if tagging_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            tagging_serializer.save(tagging=request.data)
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": tagging_serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response({"status": "error", "data": tag_serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I am handling most of the logic in the TaggingSerializer:

```
class TaggingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  tag = TagSerializer(required=False, write_only=False)
  resource_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Resource.objects.all(),
                                                   required=True,
                                                   source='resource',
                                                   write_only=False)
  gameround_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Gameround.objects.all(),
                                                    required=False,
                                                    source='gameround',
                                                    write_only=False)
  user_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=CustomUser.objects.all(),
                                               required=False,
                                               source='user',
                                               write_only=False)

  class Meta:
    model = Tagging
    fields = ('id', 'user_id', 'gameround_id', 'resource_id', 'tag', 'created', 'score', 'origin')
    depth = 1

  def create(self, validated_data):
    """Create and return a new tagging"""

    user = None
    request = self.context.get("request")
    if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
      user = request.user

    score = 0
    tag_data = validated_data.pop('tag', None)
    if tag_data:
      tag = Tag.objects.get_or_create(**tag_data)[0]
      validated_data['tag'] = tag
      if not Tag.objects.all().filter(name=tag.name).exists():
        score = 0
      elif Tag.objects.all().filter(name=tag.name).exists():
        score += 5
      elif Tag.objects.all().filter(name=tag.name) in coordinated_gameround_tags:
        score += 25

    tagging = Tagging(
      user=user,
      gameround=validated_data.get("gameround"),
      # resource=request.query_params['resource'].id,
      resource=validated_data.get("resource"),
      tag=validated_data.get("tag"),
      created=datetime.now(),
      score=score,
      origin=""
    )
    tagging.save()
    return tagging

  def to_representation(self, instance):
    rep = super().to_representation(instance)
    rep['tag'] = TagSerializer(instance.tag).data
    return rep
```

I have tried accessing the resource from the get request with request.query_params but this also does not seem to work. When testing my post request in Postman I keep getting the error "resource_id": ["This field is required"].

Am I using request.query_params the wrong way? Is there another way to access this particular object that I don't know of? How else can I solve this?

Comment: how are you supposed to get "resource" from `validated_data.get("resource")` ? I dont see that field in your serializer fields

Comment: I am referencing it in the field with "source='resource'".